# How to use the blend / tblend filter with the t variable and between statement in FFMPEG

Tags: video, time, ffmpeg, command-line-interface, blend

I want to use the `blend` or `tblend` filters in conjunction with the `t` variable's `between` statement. I'm open to other solutions that will achieve the same effect.

I know an image can be transposed over a video, e.g. between `00:00:01.000` to `00:00:02.000`:

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i input.jpg -filter_complex \ "[0:v][1:v] overlay=10:10:enable='between(t,1,2)'" output.mkv`

Blurring a video at the same time can be done with `smartblur`:

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf "smartblur=enable='between(t,1,2)'" output.mkv`

Changing the `hue angle`, e.g. by 90 degrees, can also be done:

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf "hue=h=-90:enable='between(t,1,2)'" output.mkv`

Nothing from my searches or in the official documentation, however, explains how to compose a command using the `blend` or `tblend` filters in conjunction with the `t` variable's `between` statement. I've tried a number of formulations, but they all lead to errors. Is this simply not possible? Or is there another way to structure the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [examples](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-Examples-41) in the documentation, we may multiply the frame by the evaluated condition.

Example (the input is from [here](https://superuser.com/a/1704747/635712)):

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.mp4 -i in.gif -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[v1][v0];[v0][v1]blend=all_expr='A*if(between(T, 2, 6), 0.3, 1)+B*if(between(T, 2, 6), 0.7, 0)'" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv444p -crf 17 -acodec copy out.mp4
```

- `A` applies the frame from the first video stream - `[v0]`.
- `B` applies the frame from the second video stream - `[v1]`.
- `if(between(T, 2, 6), 0.3, 1)` is evaluated to `0.3` when time is between 2 and 6 seconds, and evaluated to `1` otherwise.
- `if(between(T, 2, 6), 0.7, 0)` is evaluated to `0.7` when time is between 2 and 6 seconds, and evaluated to `0` otherwise.
- The entire expression is evaluated to `0.3*A + 0.7*B` between 2 and 6 and `1*A + 0*B` otherwise.

Sample output (between 2 and 6 seconds):
[image]

Note:
I think there is a bug regarding the exact time, but it could be related to my input.

---

We may also chain two `blend` filters if required.
The first blend applies some blending effect, and the second blend selects when to use the effect and when to use the original video stream.
Example:

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.mp4 -i in.gif -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[v1][v0];[v0][v1]blend=all_mode=grainextract[b];[0:v][b]blend=all_expr='A*if(between(T, 2, 6), 0, 1)+B*if(between(T, 2, 6), 1, 0)'" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv444p -crf 17 -acodec copy out.mp4
```

---

Another option is to chain `blend` with `overlay` filter.

Comment: I suspect that in your second application of `blend` the first input should be `[v0]` rather than `[0:v]`, right? (Because you want to mix the resized version.) Just checking in case I misunderstood something.

Comment: …and even then it may not work, unless `[v0]` goes through additional splitting before the second blend (I’m trying something similar and running into this stuff)

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff You are right, it should be something like: `ffmpeg -y -i in.mp4 -i in.gif -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[v1][v0];[v0]split[v0a][v0b];[v0a][v1]blend=all_mode=grainextract[b];[v0b][b]blend=all_expr='A*if(between(T, 2, 6), 0, 1)+B*if(between(T, 2, 6), 1, 0)'" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv444p -crf 17 -acodec copy out.mp4`