# How to use multiple between statements with the blend filter in ffmpeg

Tags: if-statement, video, ffmpeg, command-line, blending

The command below blends `input2` into `input1` using a binary of `*if` expressions featuring the `between` statement's `t` variable. As such, `output` = `input1`, but with `input2` at `00:00:03- 00:00:05`:

`ffmpeg -y -i input1.mkv -i input2.mkv -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[v1][v0];[v0][v1]blend=all_expr='A*if(between(T, 3, 5), 0, 1)+B*if(between(T, 3, 5), 1, 0)'" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv444p -crf 18 -acodec copy output.mkv`

My question is how these can be chained together in the case of a set of evaluated conditions. I've attempted the `+` operator, below, but `input1` is no longer the same. It seems distorted by multiple layers of the video.

`ffmpeg -y -i input1.mkv -i input2.mkv -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[v1][v0];[v0][v1]blend=all_expr='A*if(between(T, 3, 5), 0, 1)+B*if(between(T, 3, 5), 1, 0)'+'A*if(between(T, 7, 9), 0, 1)+B*if(between(T, 7, 9), 1, 0)'" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv444p -crf 18 -acodec copy output.mkv`

How can these be chained together without producing visual artifacts?

This question is a follow-up to [Rotem's solution to my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71100287/how-to-use-the-blend-tblend-filter-with-the-t-variable-and-between-statement-i/71105570#71105570).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want only `[v1]` between [3, 5] and between [7, 9], and `[v0]` otherwise, make sure that `B` is multiplied by `1` between {[3, 5], [7, 9]} and `A` is multiplied by `0` between {[3, 5], [7, 9]}, and vice versa.

We may use the following command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input1.mkv -i input2.mkv -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[v1][v0];[v0][v1]blend=all_expr='A*not((between(T, 3, 5)+between(T, 7, 9)))+B*(between(T, 3, 5)+between(T, 7, 9))'" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv444p -crf 18 -acodec copy output.mkv
```

---

Since it's just `0` and `1`, we don't have to use the `if` expression.

According to [Expression Evaluation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#toc-Expression-Evaluation) documentation:

> between(x, min, max)
> Return 1 if x is greater than or equal to min and lesser than or equal to max, 0 otherwise.

> not(expr)
> Return 1.0 if expr is zero, 0.0 otherwise.

- `(between(T, 3, 5)+between(T, 7, 9))` is evaluated to `1` in range {[3, 5], [7, 9]}, and evaluated to `0` otherwise.
- `not(between(T, 3, 5)+between(T, 7, 9))` is evaluated to `0` in range {[3, 5], [7, 9]}, and evaluated to `1` otherwise.